# $\lim_{x\to 0} {[\sqrt{2} x]\over x}$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to 0} {[\sqrt{2} x]\over x}=\sqrt{2}-\lim_{x\to 0}{\{\sqrt{2} x\}\over x}$

Now $\lim_{x\to 0}{\{\sqrt{2} x\}\over x}=0$, how will I make understand to my school students who do not know the epsilon delta definition of limit.

Comment: you can use sequence $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Do the brackets $[\dots]$ and braces $\{\dots\}$ represent anything special? Also, is the radical meant to also cover the $x$? Thanks!

Comment: that is box function i mean greattest integer function, and $\{x\}$ denote fractional part of $x$

Answer (score 2):

If $[x]$ is the *floor* function and $\{x\} = x - [x]$ then I think you are wrong. In fact $[\sqrt 2 x]=0$ if $x \to 0^+$ while $[\sqrt 2 x] = -1$ if $x\to 0^-$ hence the given limit does not exist.